# DRDY signal in Verilog

Tags: counter, verilog

in my recent CPLD design I implemented a frequency counter with an SPI slave interface. The SPI master MCU reads out the counter after it is signalled by a DRDY pin. My counter updates the DRDY signal by flipping it (DRDY <=~DRDY) but it requires both edges pin interrupt sensitivity at the MCU side.  I'd like to implement it more universally, like the typical ADC chip data ready signal behaviour, which is: a rising edge, held for x clocks then a falling edge. I thought it should be easy however I stucked in conditional loops as a beginner in Verilog.

Here is my code so far:

```
module ec2(INP, RST, SR, DRDY, DRDY2, DRDY3);

input INP, RST, SR;
output reg DRDY2, DRDY3;//LEDs for verification/testing purposes
output reg DRDY;
reg [23:0] Q;


event data_ready;



always @(posedge INP or negedge RST)
begin
    if(!RST)
        begin
        Q <= 24'd0;
        end
    else if( (Q == 24'd1000000 && SR) || (Q == 24'd500000 && !SR)) 
        begin
            Q <= 24'd0;
            ->data_ready;
            DRDY2 <=~DRDY2;
        end             
    else
        begin   
        Q <= Q + 1;
        end
end

always @(data_ready)
    begin
        DRDY=1'b1;
        //wait for 10ms?
        DRDY=1'b0;
        DRDY3 = DRDY2;

    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Events are not synthesizable, you should convert data_ready into a signal (reg).  A second counter which triggers DRDY at data_ready assertion would do the trick:

```
always @(posedge INP or negedge RST)
  begin
    if (RST)
      begin
        DRDY <= 1'b0;
        drdy_count <= 4'd0;
      end
    else
      begin
        if (~DRDY && data_ready)
          begin
            DRDY <= 1'b1;
            drdy_count <= 4'd0;
          end
        else if (DRDY)
          begin
            drdy_count <= drdy_count + 1;
            if (drdy_count == 15)
              DRDY <= 1'b0;
          end
      end
  end
```